# does placing object on Flash pro cs6 stage uses starling for stage3d acceleration or uses old Flash?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5.5, starling-framework, flash-cs6

To make 2d games with stage3d hardware acceleration ,it's best to use  starling framework ,and starling tutorials do not use flash pro cs6 ,and designing levels is done  in code ,so does that mean because flash pro cs6 use old Flash API ,and it does not have hardware acceleration , I mean if you convert an art on stage to a movie clip with flash pro cs6 ,does Flash editor Do it like 
Flash.display.MoviClip
Or
Starling.display.MoviClip ?

and if Flash pro cs6 use "flash.display.MovieClip", does that kill performance, or your game does not have to be all starling to get stgae3d hardware acceleration  ?

Comment: You can't use the flash timeline with starling.  You CAN use it to make sprite sheets to import at run time into starling.   Anything you do on the timeline extends `flash.display...`

Comment: Is there is a plan form Adobe to change that , and then what the point of Flash pro if it's not optimized for stage3d ?

Comment: Probably not in the near future. Looking at Flash's history, it started mainly as a lightweight vector graphics animation package. Vector graphics and small file sizes were great for the earlier days of the internet when it was mostly consumed on slow connections and desktop computers. It's only in Flash CS5.5/6 that SpriteSheet support and hardware acceleration(on the release builds) was added, so at the moment mostly developers can take advantage of the performance. This might improve for designers in the future, but still there's use for the traditional vector functionalities and ...

Comment: ...and integrating the two won't be an easy task while maintaining compatibility. There are still plenty of use cases where hardware acceleration is a bit overkill.

Answer (score 0):

Starling is a third party library. It is encouraged and funded by Adobe, but it is not part of the Flash platform itself. Therefore, Flash Pro does not use Starling. In other words, there is only one Flash Drawing API, and obviously Flash Pro uses it when creating vector drawings.

The Flash drawing API does not use Stage3D, and does not use GPU hardware acceleration.

However, it is wrong to assume that you **need** to use Stage3D to get good performance on a 2D game. The vast majority of games, including plenty of complicated, high-performance ones, do not.

To understand better what Stage3D is and how it works, I recommend [How Stage3D works](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/how-stage3d-works.html).